# xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 5: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

I am learning android and wanted to perform xml parsing using SAXParser. my issue is when i run my code i get the following error:

org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 5: not well-formed (invalid token)
i have gone through similar cases reported on stackoverflow.com but none of the solutions provided have fixed my issue

here is my code:

```
public List<RssItem> getItems() throws Exception {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    //Creates a new RssHandler which will do all the parsing.
    RssHandler handler = new RssHandler();

    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(rssUrl));

    source.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    saxParser.parse(source, handler);


    return handler.getRssItemList();
```

the xml feed iam trying to parse is: http://t.arabi21.com/rss

Kindly help me to overcome this issue.

thanks a lot

Comment: Its expecting to see an <xml> tag for the first element.  Its missing here.  Since you likely don't control the source, you may want to try adding it.

Comment: can you please guide me on how to add <xml> tag as the source first element in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add XML declaration like

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

in the beginning, before your

```
 <rss version="2.0">
```

element.

Comment: @user2198400 You should accept the answer if it did work for you.